# Modular Arithmetic in R

Tags: r, modular-arithmetic

I'm quite new to R and I've been wondering if there is a way to perform modular arithmetic, either in base R or any package, I have not found anything/thought of anything so far.

If it is not clear what i mean by modular arithmetic, i mean something like, if you have set/module like c(1,2,3,4,5), if you add 7 to 1, you would end up with a two, so it sorta wraps around. I've been coping with the lack of this kind of operation by using  `if`  statements, adding special conditions for numbers that go above the max number un a module/set, but right now i'm in the need of performing actual modular arithmetic.

I hope this isn't a too much of a open ended question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See `%%` and `%/%`.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html integer division and modulo operators.

Comment: thanks so much, I realize the silliness of my question now.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of this, you might find the `VeryLargeIntegers` package helpful.